# List all files not starting with a number

Tags: regex, linux, shell, ls

I want to examine the all the key files present in my `/proc`. But `/proc` has innumerable directories corresponding to the running processes. I don't want these directories to be listed. All these directories' names contain only numbers. As I am poor in regular expressions, can anyone tell me whats the `regex` that I need to send to `ls` to make it **NOT** to search files/directories which have numbers in their name?

**UPDATE**: Thanks to all the replies! But I would love to have a `ls` alone solution instead of `ls+grep` solution. The `ls` alone solutions offered till now doesn't seem to be working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All files and directories in `/proc` which do not contain numbers (in other words, excluding process directories):

```
ls -d /proc/[^0-9]*
```

All files recursively under `/proc` which do not start with a number:

```
find /proc -regex '.*/[0-9].*' -prune -o -print
```

**But** this will also exclude numeric files in *subdirectories* (for example `/proc/foo/bar/123`). If you want to exclude only the top-level files with a number:

```
find /proc -regex '/proc/[0-9].*' -prune -o -print
```

Hold on again! Doesn't this mean that any [regular files](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) created by `touch /proc/123` or the like will be excluded? Theoretically yes, but I don't think you can do that. Try creating a file for a PID which does not exist:

```
$ sudo touch /proc/123
touch: cannot touch `/proc/123': No such file or directory
```

Comment: `ls -d /proc/[^0-9]*` lists precisely the directories containing numbers( Which I don't want :( ) i.e Process directories! Something's fishy here too!

Comment: @Stacker: Which OS are you on? What does `ls --version` return? I've run this on two different distros (Ubuntu 64-bit and Linux Mint 64-bit, GNU `ls` 8.5 on one machine at least), and it shows only files and directories *without* numbers, from `/proc/acpi` to `/proc/zoneinfo`. *`ls` is notoriously unportable*, so it might just be that `-d` does something completely different in your version.

Comment: Oops! You are right! I ran your command on my Ubuntu 11.10 and it works just fine! I was on AIX 6.1, the other day ( reconfirmed again) and it breaks!! I'm confused as to why! `man ls` and searching for `-d` almost gives similar explanation on both systems that directories will be treated as any other files! Why this differnece?!

Answer (score 8):

You don't need grep, just `ls`:

```
ls -ad /proc/[^0-9]*
```

if you want to search the whole subdirectory structure use find:

```
find /proc/ -type f -regex "[^0-9]*" -print
```

Comment: I think something's wrong with your `ls` solution. It is listing all files inside the folders starting with numbers! I dont want the directories which start with number at all!

Comment: Even the `find` solution is rushing into folders with numbers in their names! Am I missing anything?

Comment: -1 Did anyone except @Stacker try these commands? The `ls` lists the correct files, but also lists directory contents of `/proc/*/`. And the `find` clearly lists all process directories and their files.

Comment: @Stacker : sorry missed an option

Comment: `find` takes the option `-type d`.

Comment: @l0b0 : the find command lists filenames, that do not start with a digit, it is not concerned with the path, so yes it will descend into directories of processes, this is an option, NOT a must!

Comment: @Mithrandir: The OP wanted to exclude "directories corresponding to the running processes", and the command does something else altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Use grep with `-v` which tells it to print all lines *not matching* the pattern.

```
 ls /proc | grep -v '[0-9+]'
```

Answer (score 1):

`ls /proc | grep -v -E '[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 0):

Following regex matches all the characters except numbers

```
^[\D]+?$
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of of completion. You may apply Mithandir's answer with find.

```
  find . -name "[^0-9]*" -type f
```