# find all files that do not begin with a specific char?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using this code to find all php files in a bash script.

```
for f in $(find ./src -name '*.php'); 
do 
    echo "$f"; 
done
```

How can i go through all *.php files but ignore ones that start with _ ?

For example it should list index.php, but not _menu.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `... -name "[^_]*.php"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find all files that do not begin with a given prefix in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21368838/608639), [List all files not starting with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9515263/608639), [find filenames NOT ending in specific extensions on Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1341467/608639), etc.

Comment: Do you mean the first letter of the filename, or the first character in the content?

Comment: `find /path -type f -name "*php" ! -name "_*"`

Comment: @kvantour see the example „but not _menu.php“

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-name` parameter does allow *fnmatch* style globing patterns, which is not a regular expression and has no negative patterns. So you need one of two alternatives (if you want to filter inside the find operation):

You have the option to use a RE instead. You need to be aware that regular expressions match against the whole path not the name only, so something like this should work:

```
find ./src -regex '.*/[^_/][^/]*\.php'
```

An alternative is to combine `-name` with a negation expression (`-a -not` means „and not“):

```
find ./src -name '*.php' -a -not -name '_*'
```

Comment: I like the second one better I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ./src -name '[^_]*.php' | \
while read -r filename; do
   echo "$filename"
done
```

**explanation**

```
[^_]*     # all characters without _ at start
```

Comment: Actually `[^_]*` means zero or more characters but none of them are  `_`, and you cannot use RE with -name.